# Creating user with /sbin/nologin, any benefit to running passwd and setting to random

Tags: security, users, login, password

If creating a user with a shell of `/sbin/nologin`, is there any benefit / need to running `passwd usernamegoeshere` after creating the user and setting the password to something random or is that of no benefit?

I don't think this changes the answer, but this user might be used by cron for example as a way to run cron jobs with non-elevated privileges.  It's not intended to be logged into by anyone via ssh, nor should they be permitted to do so.

Comment: I think password less ssh will still require the password be valid.

Comment: @Bratchley I might not understand, but in this case nobody would be using SSH to log in as the user, so just need to ensure that by not running `passwd` it doesn't leave open the possibility that someone could authenticate as the user (such as by running `su -s /bin/bash usernamegoeshere` as a non-root user).  I guess maybe another way to word my question is when a user is created, can anyone authenticate as them using a password if `passwd` hasn't been run (like does a default password get set that's not secure or something I'm not thinking of).  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically for `nologin` shells you may want to also *lock* the account or set the password to be *invalid*.  In `/etc/shadow` on Linux a locked account would have a password entry looking like `!!` and an invalid password would be `*`

eg on Debian Jessie:

```
/etc/passwd:backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/usr/sbin/nologin
/etc/shadow:backup:*:16274:0:99999:7:::
```

On CentOS 7

```
/etc/passwd:sshd:x:74:74:Privilege-separated SSH:/var/empty/sshd:/sbin/nologin
/etc/shadow:sshd:!!:16628::::::
```

Now it doesn't matter what is entered at the password prompt, it *can not* work.

Comment: Perfect - I confirmed it has the `!!` (CentOS 7)

Answer (score 0):

Programs that rely on the password file for authentication ***typically*** fail when set to use the `/sbin/nologin` shell.

But that doesn't mean that it's not a good idea to set the password to something really strong, just in case some ***flawed*** program would ignore the shell specified.

Your approach seems like a fairly good idea although it may never be practically useful.